# Why do I get different outputs in case of sh and bash?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have the following simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Bash version ${BASH_VERSION}..."
for i in {1..99..2}
do
        echo $i
done
```

Output in case I run with `sh file.sh`:

```
Bash version ...
{1..99..2}
```

Output in case I run with `bash file.sh`:

```
Bash version 4.2.25(1)-release...
1
3
5
.
.
.
99
```

I have two queries:

1. If I have written a shabang line specifying shell, shouldn't it run with bash whether I use `sh file.sh` or `bash file.sh`?
2. I understand that `$BASH_VERSION` is not recognized by sh but what is the problem with for loop? Why isn't printing the numbers?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`sh`, the Bourne shell, is **old**. Its behaviour is specified by [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html). If you want new behaviour, you use `bash`, the Bourne Again shell, which gets new features added to it all the time. On many systems, `sh` is just `bash`, and `bash` turns on a compatibility mode when run under that name. On Ubuntu, `sh` is [`dash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/dash.1.html), the Debian Almquist shell.

The brace expansion is a relatively [new feature](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92819/70524), and would not be available in older bashes as well. It certainly shouldn't be in `sh`.

The shebang line is only respected if you call the script as an executable:

```
./myscript.sh
```

I can give a script any shebang and still have it open in Python by running:

```
python myscript.sh
```

See these excellent questions on Unix & Linux:

- [Does the shebang determine the shell which runs the script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87560/70524)
- [Different ways to execute a shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2976/70524)

Answer (score 5):

SH is stupid. It can not do anything.

It only knows the most basic commands. It does not do anything else.

It can not understand {1..99} as a numeric value. It understands it as a string.

SH/Dash is not developed. It is meant to be an emergency prompt for DIRE circumstances (in interactive mode. Otherwise, it's a really good thing for scripting.).

Bash is recommended as it can do everything SH can, as well as the newest in customization and powerful features.

In answer to #1, the `#!` is only parsed if the program is called directly. (as in, `./program.sh`)

Comment: "*It is meant to be an emergency prompt for DIRE circumstances.*" [`dash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/dash.1.html), which as you say provides `sh` in Ubuntu, isn't present mainly "to be an emergency prompt for DIRE circumstances" but instead [so the system can run, and *start*, fast](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh). In this way, `dash` is well suited to use in a modern OS, but what it's well suited *for* is as a low-profile, fast shell for scripting--particularly, running system scripts while booting a big, complex, modern OS, with minimal performance overhead.

Comment: @EliahKagan You really only use SH if something when terribly wrong.

Comment: You use `sh` pretty constantly, and particularly intensively as Ubuntu boots. *It's mainly important for its automated scripting uses, and that is a very important use case in Ubuntu.* (If you were to *remove* the `/bin/sh` symlink--so that, in effect, there would be "no SH"--things would go terribly wrong: Ubuntu could not boot up into a usable state.)

Comment: @EliahKagan When did you last use SH as your preferred terminal? I know you use it to script, but when do you actually use it in interactive mode?

Comment: Yesterday, to check how portable a command was. But your point that interactive use of dash is rare is valid. (And anyway, the context of my interactive use was still scripting-oriented.) ....But "use" does not mean "interactive use," and more importantly, *the use case in this question is not an interactive one!*

Comment: @EliahKagan Meh. I already know I'm an idiot. I also confess to not using Ubuntu for 2-3 weeks now (stupid dependency on OneNote). Forgive me if I'm not wholly right on my use of `sh`. I personally always use bash and know nobody in my department that uses sh. /no_sarcasm