# Same script opened in three different ways produces three different results. Why?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts

I have a sample script (credit goes to [kos](https://askubuntu.com/users/380067/kos)):

```
#!/bin/bash
cat <(cat /etc/lsb-release)
```

I save this script as **somename.sh** in my home directory.

Now, I try to open this file in three different ways:

```
sh somename.sh

bash somename.sh

./somename.sh
```

So, I have two questions:

1. Why are the outputs for the above commands different though they are running the same script?

   - **sh** produces a Syntax error
   - **bash** outputs the desired result
   - **./** gives a Permission Denied error
2. Why is it necessary to give the script executable permission only when running the script using **./** and not necessary in the other cases?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: The first part might be similar to the [duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517893) linked one but, I did have a second question too.

Comment: In the last case: a script simply needs to be run either with the preceding language, *or* needs to be executable. In the latter case, the shebang is needed to tell the language the script should run with. The first two: sh is not the same as bash. That is explained elsewhere on the site.

Comment: One could say when the script is run with the preceding language, the language is running the script. If the script runs with a shebang, without preceding language, the script "calls" the language, to run the code inside the script. The script then needs permission to do so.

Comment: Also see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2976/70524

Comment: And that's why you should stick to one question per post.

Comment: @muru - But those questions are related.

Comment: So? Post two questions and link to each other.

Comment: @muru - Ok! Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As we discussed in the chat:

1. `sh script` produces an error because calling the interpreter directly (in this case `sh`) ignores the shebang, and the script is run in `sh`; `sh` doesn't support process substitutions (`<([...])`), which are Bash-isms, so the script exits on error.

   `bash script` doesn't produce an error because despite the shebang being ignored the script is still run in Bash, which supports process substitutions.

   `./script` produces an error because `script` is not executable.
2. To run a script with `./` you *must* have the execute bit for your user set on the script, that's an OS' constraint.

   So the question actually is: *why doesn't `bash script` require  having the execute bit set for your user on `script`*?

   That's because when running `bash script` the script is read by Bash, and Bash *has* the execute bit set for your user.

   That means that Bash, having the permission to execute code, can "bypass" the OS' constraint on that script, and all the script needs is to be readable by Bash.

Answer (score 5):

- `sh` is symlink to `dash` shell and produces a Syntax error because there is no `<( . . .)` in `sh` syntax. It's only in bash (and in `zsh` and `ksh` if I remember correctly ).
- bash outputs the desired result because it's in right bash syntax, nothing wrong there
- ./ gives a Permission Denied error because you basically say "Hey, shell, look at the permissions of that file and look at the first line (the one with `#!/bin/bash` ) in my *current directory* and figure out how to run this script for me". (side note: if you had the script in a location that is included into your `$PATH` variable, then you would just run `myScriptName.sh` and that's it, but the idea would be same, we need to check exec permissions and what interpreter to use)

Before you were running `bash` and `dash` and telling them to read commands from file. `bash` and `dash` are executable this time, not the script. Script now is source of commands, a parameter. Read permissions there are always set for all users, so shells will read it.

Comment: @kos  I keep forgetting zhs because I don't actively use it \ ( -_- ) /  . . . not yet . . .

Answer (score 3):

In general `sh`,`ash`,`dash`,`bash`,`csh`,`tcsh`,`zsh`... are all shells with their own syntaxes and characteristics. There are some compatibilities but they are *oriented* <sup>[[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145522/what-does-it-mean-to-be-sh-compatible)]</sup>: a `bash` shell will execute a `sh` script but it is not said the *viceversa*. A `sh` invocation required less resources than a `bash` one. For one single instance it is not a problem, for thousands it should be.

**Ways to execute.**
To execute a file as a program under Linux, both if it is a script or a compiled one, it has to be set the *execute bit* <sup>[[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions)]</sup> and it has to be included in one of the directories of your `$PATH`.

If it is a script, it can be passed as argument to the relative shell (`sh`,`bash`...`myfile.whatever`): if it is passed to the **wrong shell** you can obtain a not correct behaviour and **if you are lucky an error**; in this case **it doesn't need to be executable** because it is like if you were writing the lines written inside the script directly **in the new shell** that you are invoking. 
To execute in the same shell instead you can use `source myfile` or `. myfile` that are the equivalent to write line by line **in the current shell** the content of the script.

**Location**
If the executable program is not included in your path, you have to specify where it can be found.

- In your case the **`./`** means only the current directory of your shell, as well `~/myfile.whatever` should address the file `myfile.whatever` in your home `~/` directory.
- You can invoke it from another location for example with `/home/$USER/dir/myfile.whatever`.
- If this file is inside a directory included in your path you can invoke it with a simple `myfile.whatever`.

In the case that the more than one executable are sharing the same name, specifying the full path will be sure about which one you are going to execute. `which mycommand` is able to tell you which one will be executed now (a function, an alias, a built in or the first found in your path), but it cannot say which one will be executed in a future time or from another user. If you expressly write the full path you will fix this ambiguity. It is useful to execute a specific version of a program when are installed more that one on the same time...and to avoid trojan. In a script it is always suggested to write `/bin/bash` instead of `bash`.