# read: Illegal option -s while requesting user input for password

Tags: bash, scripts, password

I am using the following command to request a password from the user in a bash script and I get the error " read: Illegal option -s"

Command that I am using in the script - read -s -p "Password: " pass

This command is working when I run it from the shell, whereas it is not working when I incorporate it in my bash shell script.

Comment: How exactly are you executing your bash script? A common newbie error is to do something like `sh path/to/script`, which runs it using the `/bin/sh` shell instead of the bash shell. See the related answer here [Why do I get different outputs in case of sh and bash?](https://askubuntu.com/a/517895/178692)