# Brace expansion not working within shell script

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to use brace expansion in a shell script to create a directory structure but I am not getting the desired effect.

With the line `sudo mkdir -pv /opt/test/{one,two,three}-way`, issuing the command directly to the shell I get the intended result. If I have this within a script, it creates a path `opt/test/{one,two,three}-way`

Shell result:

```
jwright@ubuntu-server:/$ sudo mkdir -pv /opt/test/{one,two,three}-way
[sudo] password for jwright: 
mkdir: created directory '/opt/test'
mkdir: created directory '/opt/test/one-way'
mkdir: created directory '/opt/test/two-way'
mkdir: created directory '/opt/test/three-way'
```

Script result:

```
jwright@ubuntu-server:~$ sudo sh setup.sh
[sudo] password for jwright: 
mkdir: created directory '/opt/test1'
mkdir: created directory '/opt/test1/{one,two,three}-way'
```

You can see from the output that I am running the shell as sudo.

Comment: I have tried with and witout `sudo` actually in the script itself

Comment: Don't try to run the script with `sh` - brace expansion is not a POSIX shell capability - it's supported by `bash` (and `ksh` and `zsh`) but not by `sh`

Comment: ... see [Why do I get different outputs in case of sh and bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517893/why-do-i-get-different-outputs-in-case-of-sh-and-bash)

Comment: Note that the "shell result" example expands the braces in your shell _before_ passing the expanded arguments to sudo.

Answer (score 0):

With the command `sh setup.sh`, you instruct the `dash` shell to interpret the script. The `dash` shell is the system wide default shell in Ubuntu, whereas the more "heavy" (and bash developpers themselves even say "bloated" `bash` shell is used for interactive shells (your prompt at the terminal).

`dash` is light and more minimal, and does not support all features of `bash`. That includes bracket expansion. If you want to use bash specific features in your script, then load it with bash:

`bash setup.sh`

If you make the script executable, then the *shebang* line is what you use to indicate which interpreter should run the script. This is a very first line in a script, included as a comment:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

If the script is made executable, then run by typing its name (`/path/to/setup.sh` or `./setup.sh` if the script is in the current directory, or just `setup.sh` if the script is in the PATH searched by the system for executable), this directive will tell it to be run with `bash`.

The shebang line will *not* be honored if you start the script as an argument to the interpreter. Thus, even if the shebang line would be there, `sh setup.sh` will still be using `dash` rather than `bash`.